# Testing a callback is called or not called when parent is destroyed (dependent: :destroy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, mocha.js, minitest

I'm wondering if there's a way to test wether a callback on a child object is called (`before/after_destroy`) when the parent triggers the destroy via `dependent: :destroy`? Obviously we can't access the object created in the destroy process.

I'm using MiniTest and the Mocha gem if that helps. I suspect it may have something to do with mocking the relationship and also the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how strict isolation we wish to use.

Let's say we have  this example in Rails 4:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  after_destroy :after_destroy_method

  def after_destroy_method
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I would recommend using some isolation anyway, because it is not the Post's model responsibility to know, what should happen after a comment gets destroyed. So testing the right behaviour of the callbacks should go into the Comment model test.

**Strict isolation:**

We know if we apply `dependent: :destroy` on the relationship then Rails will do its job and call the callbacks (it is tested and working like charm). So only thing to test:

- we use `dependent: :destroy` in the right place. For this we can use [Shoulda Matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) in the Post model test like this: `should have_many(:comments).dependent(:destroy)`

**Not so strict isolation:**

It is getting closer to the integration testing, in the Post model test:

```
test "calls #after_destroy_method on the comments after a post gets destroyed" do
  post = Post.create title: "Test title"
  Comment.create post: post

  Comment.any_instance.expects(:after_destroy_method)

  post.destroy
end
```

Comment: Ahhh! `.any_instance` is what I was looking for without knowing it :) That's definitely the solution I needed. This is for a gem rather than a straight Rails project so it's important to test that our additional callbacks fire or don't fire.

Answer (score 0):

You should test if the transformations that are in the before/after_destroy block are done.

Did it update the DB? Did the mocked object get called?

Comment: The trouble is, the callback that I'm testing does a DB update on its sibling records before it is destroyed. When the siblings are also destroyed (via the dependent: :destroy) then there is no trace left wether the update occurred or not.

Comment: The PR in question is here: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/pull/261 where we're trying to prevent superfluous updates when we know all siblings will be destroyed anyway.